# Magento 2 docker image

Tags: magento2, docker

I am looking for a docker image that can run my already installed Magento 2 instance with `php7`.

So I have a working Magento 2 installation (previously created with MAMP) and I would like to be able to create a container that will use those already existing files.

Currently, the available images like mageinferno and alankent create a new Magento 2 application from scratch.

I tried to create my own but I'm running into all sort of permission issues in the var folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://hub.docker.com/r/rafaelcgstz/magento2/

I created some images to Magento, this image to Magento 2 has:

- PHP 7.0
- Apache 2.4
- Composer
- MariaDB
- Magerun
- DevAlias CLI
- Utils (GIT, VIM, UNZIP, CURL, WGET)

Execute in your terminal, change the MYMAGENTO2 to use the name of your project:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clean-docker/Magento2/master/init | bash -s MYMAGENTO2 clone
```

If you want to install the Magento 2, use like that:

```
cd MYMAGENTO2
./shell
rm index.php
install-magento2
```

Comment: do you have any suggestion to how to create Magento 2 docker  Image from scratch ? @Rafael

Comment: @KeyurShah This image I created to development (mainly in Linux), the better way is using OPCache + MariaDB + PHP 7. To Mac and Windows can use the DevBox Official Docker image of Magento.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , but could you please provide me any link or tutorial to create docker Image . I am sorry for this question , I am beginner in docker so :) @RafaelCorrêaGomes

Comment: @KeyurShah This link will to help you https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/

Comment: Hi @RafaelCorrêaGomes could you help in this docker image for magento related question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268318/how-to-create-custom-module-after-installing-magento-2-docker-image

Answer (score 1):

You can use this image from Docker Hub https://hub.docker.com/r/folio3ecommerce/magento-php-apache

There are available tags for `2.4.3-p1, 2.4.4-p2, 2.4.5`

The above image includes:

```
PHP 7.4, 8.1
Apache2
Magento code including Sample data
```

You just need to pull this image and import the available database (.sql file on container's root directory /var/www/html)

This is a pure fresh Magento instance with Sample Data. Hope this helps!

Sample **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '3'

services:
  magento:
    image: folio3ecommerce/magento-php-apache:2.4.5
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:80"
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env
    links:
      - db
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - customNetwork
    
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    restart: on-failure
    command: --max_allowed_packet=256M
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.16.2
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${ES_PORT}:9200"
      - "${ES_SSL_PORT}:9300"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearchdata:/var/lib/elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      ## Set custom heap size to avoid memory errors
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
      ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
      - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
      - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"
    networks:
      - customNetwork

volumes:
  dbdata:
  redisdata:
  elasticsearchdata:

networks:
  customNetwork:
```

Comment: Thanks @ahsan this image is useful. Can you please confirm if the image also contains required composer version along with some useful tools like vim.

Comment: It does include require composer version but does not include vim in the old images. However, in the 2.4.6 image, nano editor has been added and you can install any editor as well. But you can try to install vim on the image you are using, let me know the results