# How to create custom module after installing Magento 2 Docker Image?

Tags: magento2, image, docker, command, directory

I have installed **Magento docker Image** and frontend, backend is working fine. The directory structure of Magento docker Image installed is:

[image]

**Now I am looking how to start my first module. I have these concerns:**

> 1. Where are magento files like app, pub, var, vendor that we get on downloading normal magento version.
> 2. How do we run magento commands like static-content:deploy or setup:upgrade when we are usinng docker

My machine is `macOS Mojave 14.10.2`.

**Thanks.**

Comment: dont you see any app folder?

Comment: no there is not app folder, I guess in this case we create at src/app/code but don't know how to run commands for magento..

Comment: what is the name of your DOCKER IMAGE ?

Comment: I had it from here https://github.com/alexcheng1982/docker-magento2

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8DqsUGFB6g might this would help you.

Comment: Man this is what I have done already..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91859/discussion-between-i-ali55-and-ajwad-taqvi).